# Android service restart on Play store app upgrade

Tags: android, service, updates

I'm aware of the fact that the app is uninstalled and re-installed during the course of an app update from the play store.

I have a very crucial service which needs to be running ALWAYS in the background. And this service gets killed during the update process. Is there any way to restart this service without having the user to go manually to the app (without going to the activity)?

I've implemented the following code. But somehow this doesn't work either. (Probably because the app gets uninstalled anyway)

```
public class AppUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {    
        if ("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED".equals(intent.getAction()))
            // Start service here                        
    }
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.services.AppUpdateReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>     
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Other info : minSDK = 14, Target SDK = 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm aware of the fact that the app is uninstalled and re-installed during the course of an app update from the play store

No, it is not. Your process is terminated, though.

> I have a very crucial service which needs to be running ALWAYS in the background

A user can stop your service whenever the user wants to, above and beyond the OS terminating your process whenever the OS feels that it is appropriate.

> But somehow this doesn't work either

Try to use [`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) instead and see if that helps.